# AWS s3 file downloads are not working in Chrome (Works fine with IE, Mozilla, Safari)

Tags: pdf, google-chrome, download, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am using s3 to store my pdf files. But when i tries to download the files from s3 using chrome browser it doesn't do anything. It just refresh the page, no error, nothing ...
But from other browsers i can download that file. 
When i checked in the console it gives 'Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.'

I got one thread from AWS https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=79493

But we can not tell user that go & disable this plugin & then download.

Is it a problem from AWS end?

I searched a lot but didn't get any solution.
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Vijay

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this problem too. The solution it to force Chrome to download the PDF file instead of trying to open it in its reader.

In your GET request, append `response-content-disposition=attachment`. Refer to the [S3 documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) on how to do this.

More details available [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120702185852/http://www.thingy-ma-jig.co.uk/comment/7045).

Comment: Updated link to use Wayback Machine.

Comment: on carrier_wave it will be something like this: acticle.file.url({:query => {"response-content-disposition" => "attachment"}}). https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/566

Comment: If the purpose is to display the PDF in the browser (e.g. inline display), this isn't really a solution at all. I guess I'll look into using my backend as an intermediary if the AWS links with parameters are the problems